# How to increase the coordinate resolution of a d3-geo chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a GeoJSON file with small details and features that I want to render using D3. Unfortunately, important details are lost because D3
removes polygon coordinate pairs that are closely spaced.

I've set up a small example to show this. Both links use the exact same GeoJSON data, rendered with both D3-geo and mapbox through github.
Specifically, notice the two areas marked by the red circles.

https://bl.ocks.org/alvra/eebb06be793bc06ff3ae01e6945298b6
https://gist.github.com/alvra/eebb06be793bc06ff3ae01e6945298b6

The top one one marks a part of polygon that is rounded using many closely spaced coordinate pairs, but D3 removes most points and just draws a rough square end.

The lower red circle marks a tiny triangle that is removed altogether. The adjacent polygons should touch exactly, but are also affected by D3's loss of precision.

I haven't found any documentation about D3's coordinate precision or a (configurable) feature size limit.
I've tried decreasing D3-geo's EPSILON and related EPSILON2 values and that removes this problem (for me), although I'm sure even smaller features will still be affected.

Assuming this is related to the fact that D3 uses proper geodesics for polygon segments, while the other mapping libraries just draw straight lines (in the output coordinate space),
I was hoping that this process can only introduce new points.

I haven't been able to find other users experiencing similar problems with small features, although I'm surprised this has never come up before.
Does anyone have an idea about the proper way to deal with this?

---

Through epsilon, I've narrowed the problem down to this use of [`pointEqual()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/986d3cea7f5a34384b98b747a296f63d32545f23/src/clip/circle.js#L87). This indicates the problem is with clipCircle considering closely spaced coordinates equal and removes them.
Indeed, if I disable circular clipping `projection.clipAngle(null)`, the problem disappears.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken. D3 doesn't resample the provided points: it resamples straight lines, adding points. The rate of that resampling is set by `projection.precision()` - You can see this if you set the scale to something very small - the `d` attribute of the path isn't simplified to reflect how much detail is visible. I set your scale to 400, and your entire feature fits within 1 square pixel, and  has all the original vertices. This is why it is important not to use overly detailed features with d3 - it isn't just loading time that suffers but also the rendering for invisible detail.

Comment: The value set by projection.precision() is in pixels units (per the documentation) while the error is in coordinate units (since its independent of zoom scale). Anyway, it doesn't make a difference in the posted example. This is not just the problem of detailed features but also for non-detailed but small features.
You mention resampling isn't the cause because it can only add points. It this still true if they're less than (a constant times) EPSILON apart in coordinate space, as in the example?

Comment: Hmmm, there is something very odd here. Taking a bit closer look.

Comment: I can only replicate this on azimuthal projections (such as d3.geoOrthographic), and the problem persists after removing re-sampling from d3.geo. Perhaps a precision issue in the operations used to project using the base azimuthal projection functions in d3? Your zoomed in enough you should be able to substitute a different projection (assuming that is your use case), but I'll think some more about it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this.
Zoomed out the loss of precision is irrelevant, but it would be messy to change projections on zooming in.
Looking at the use of EPSILON, the only cause that makes sense though is it's use in resample.js.

Comment: Through epsilon, I've narrowed the problem down to [pointEqual()](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/986d3cea7f5a34384b98b747a296f63d32545f23/src/clip/circle.js#L87). If I change the value of epsilon at that specific location (to 2e-7), the small features show up. I'm not sure what this means, but I hope it helps.